# Why does SQLite return different values if run with Administrator access?

Tags: sqlite

When I run the official SQLite binary provided from the authors website with the query: `SELECT DISTINCT f.id FROM foo f, bar b WHERE f.id=b.id AND b.type='baz'` it returns different results whether sqlite was run as administrator or normal. How/why can this happen?

I have no idea how to replicate this behavior to show you without providing the actual database itself (which i cannot do). Therefore any ideas to help me solve this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: the query `SELECT name, rootpage FROM sqlite_master;` is also returning different results: there are rows missing and page indexes are also different.

Comment: Are you trying to access a DB situated in Program Files under Windows Vista or more recent?

Comment: @MatteoItalia yes, do you know the problem?

Comment: That's due to automatic folder redirection. If a non-Vista aware program tries to write in Program Files with an unprivileged account, Windows silently redirects the new files into a user-specific folder, to enforce security settings without breaking old applications. In general, your application shouldn't write in Program Files.

Comment: Read http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx

Comment: @MatteoItalia Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(moving from the comments)*

That's due to automatic folder redirection. If a non-Vista aware program tries to write in Program Files with an unprivileged account, Windows silently redirects the new files into a user-specific folder, to enforce security settings without breaking old applications. In general, your application shouldn't write in Program Files.

See http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx for more info.